# How do I use MATLAB dll file in VBA code?

Tags: vba, matlab

I am trying to use a library with a MATLAB dll file in VBA code.

For testing, I created the function:

```vb
function outputArg = matlabAdd (input1, input2)
    outputArg = input1 + input2;
end
```

I tried to create libraries for C, C++, C#, .Net.
I think I'm using the file reference incorrectly.

I tested with:

```vb
Private Declare PtrSafe Function matlabAdd Lib <path>\matlabAdd" (input1 As Double, input2 As Double) As Double
```

or with add references to dll file.

The dll files were created by Library Compiler.

In the case of C/C++, I got the message

> "Can't find DLL entry point"

In the case of C#, I got the message

> Can't add a references to the specified file

Comment: You haven't told us what happened when you tried that.  "No success" is not very descriptive.

Comment: How did you create the libraries? You will also somehow have to create MATLAB arrays as input to the function.

Comment: The dll files were created by Library Compiler. In the case of C/C++, the message "Can't find DLL entry point". Could you explain "create MATLAB arrays as input to the function"

Comment: In the case of C#, I got the message "Can't add a references to the specified file"